# How to use fat-free ORM to insert data to id only table?

Tags: mysql, orm, fat-free-framework

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is work.

```
INSERT INTO `group` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);
```

But I cannot insert record using fat-free

I tried this.

```
$group=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'group');
$group->save();
```

and this.

```
$group=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'group');
$group->id=null;
$group->save();
```

and this.

```
$group=new DB\SQL\Mapper($f3->get('DB'),'group');
$group->id='null';
$group->save();
```

But no one can create record, and also no error.

What is correct way to insert record to this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fat-Free Framework's Mapper doesn't *insert* records without (changed/new) values besides the primary key. So the `$fields` array is empty and the Mapper skips the [insert operation](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/1f7bd0b1e555e206df5df1044c9505a2a5ab59e6/db/sql/mapper.php#L412-L435).

I am not sure if this qualifies as [bug](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/issues).

Here is a simple solution based on your provided query and F3's `SQL` object:

```
$sql = $f3->get('DB');
$sql->exec('INSERT INTO group (id) VALUES (NULL)');
```